# Two Or One relation table?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I Have two tables:

RH_GOALS : contains all society annual goals.

```
------------------
- GOAL_ID        -
- GOAL_INTITULE  -
------------------
```

RH_EMPLOYEE: contains all society employees.

```
------------------
- EMPLOYEE_ID    -
- FIRST_NAME     -
- LAST_NAME      -
------------------
```

Each Employee can have one Or more Goals to achieve. So I created a relationship table:
RH_EMPLOYEE_GOALS:

```
-------------------
- GOAL_ID
- EMPLOYEE_ID
- ACHIEVED (boolean)
---------------------
```

Now one employee can have others specifics goals that do not belong to the table RH_GOALS.

My question is how to represent this specifics employee goals
1- In another table: RH_EMPLOYEE_GOALS_SPECIFICS

```
--------------------
- ID
- EMPLOYEE_ID
- SPECIFIC_GOAl_INTITULE
- ACHIEVED (boolean)
---------------------
```

2- Or in the same table : RH_EMPLOYEE_GOALS

```
-------------------
- ID
- GOAL_ID (can be nuul)
- EMPLOYEE_ID
- SPECIFIC_GOAl_INTITULE
- ACHIEVED (boolean)
---------------------
```

Comment: I say in the same table

Comment: Probably just a flag in the `RH_EMPLOYEE_GOALS` specifying the type of goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

```
- ID
- GOAL_ID (can be null)
- EMPLOYEE_ID not null
- SPECIFIC_GOAl_INTITULE  (can be null)  
- ACHIEVED (boolean)
```

No need to specify any additional flags in the table.

Comment: Ok, but I have to add additional controls in my script to ensure that one of the two field are mentioned:
- GOAL_ID (can be null)
- SPECIFIC_GOAl_INTITULE  (can be null)